# EasyFind doesn't search inside .def files

Tags: applications, search

EasyFind doesn't search inside files with the extension .def. Why is this? Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: Probably a question better directed to the makers of EasyFind.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the Settings window by clicking on the cogwheel button.

   [image: Settings button]
2. Tick the 'Scan all files' checkbox.

   [image: "Scan all files" checkbox]

   Alternatively, add `def` to one of the lists (make sure to separate it with a comma from the rest of the list) and make sure the checkbox next to it is ticked.